# Rails comparison not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, have a workorders table.  Each workorder can have children workorders.  I'm trying to create dropdown links to sibling workorders.  I'm testing by looking at workorder.id = 30.  It has a sibling workorder.id = 20.  I don't want to display a link to the same workorder the user is looking at (30).

So I put in a test `<% if child.id != @workorder %>`.  But, the 30 link still displays.  I added some logger code to see what's going on.

This is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown-header">Siblings Links</li>
    <% Workorder.find(@workorder).parent.children.each do |child| %>
        <%= logger.info 'LOOK HERE ' %>
        <%= logger.info child.id %>
        <%= logger.info @workorder %>
        <% if child.id != @workorder %>
            <li><%= link_to child.id_desc, tasks_index4_path(:workorder_id => child) %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The log shows:

```
LOOK HERE
30
30
LOOK HERE
30
20
```

Yet the link_to for 30 shows up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `@workorder.to_i` in the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@workorder.to_i` in the comparison

Answer (score 1):

`@workorder` presumably is a `Workorder` object. As such, in order to compare the `@workorder` to the `child.id`, you'll need to access the `id` attribute on `@workorder` in order to make the correct comparison:

```
<% if child.id != @workorder.id %>
```